# Is there any way to improve the workability of my large Excel files

Tags: excel

I have a large Excel file that clocks in around the 3GB mark.
Sometimes it runs fairly smoothly but sometimes it may hang on a simple copy and paste and take 8 hours until it unfreezes again.

I am using 32GB of RAM but I can see it isn't enough as my "System and compressed memory" process starts to increase in size a lot when I open the file.  (I don't understand how the memory storage works because it rarely says all RAM is in use.  Right now, Excel is hanging but only 48% of my RAM is in use. ~6gb is in the compressed memory process and the Excel process is only 3.6gb (but slowly rising as it sorts itself out).

I bought a fast 64GB USB stick in order to see if readyboost might help but I haven't noticed any difference (also it will only let me use 32GB as readyboost).

Is there anything I can do to improve the situation (upgrading to 64GB of RAm isn't feasible right now) or is this just the reality of working with a 3gb Excel file?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Just to be sure, you're using a 64-bit OS and 64-bit version of Excel correct? Initial thoughts would be to consider using PowerPivot where possible. Otherwise, move the data to a database.

Comment: Yes I am using 64 bit everywhere.  I have not been using Pivot Tables/powerpivot so I will look into those, thanks.  I definitely need to improve my skills beyond Excel.  What kind of database are we talking about, Microsoft Access or something else?  Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Go Linux.
A 3 Gb Excel file probably hist the Excel hard limit of 1M rows...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).